# Extract whatever is in brackets using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-split

I really don't understand regex at all, and it hurts my head.

I've a bit of text which looks like this

```
blah blah blah (here is the bit I'd like to extract)
```

...and I don't really understand how to extract this using PHP's preg_split, or equivalent, command.

How do I do this? And where's a good place to understand how preg works?

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info/ has one of the easier introductions. And some of the tools here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world can help with constructing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick, to match what is between `(` and `)` :

```
$str = "blah blah blah (here is the bit I'd like to extract)";
if (preg_match('/\(([^\)]+)\)/', $str, $matches)) {
    var_dump($matches[1]);
}
```

And you'd get :

```
string 'here is the bit I'd like to extract' (length=35)
```

Basically, the pattern I used searches for :

- An opening `(` ; but as ( has a special meaning, it has to be escaped : `\(`
- One or more characters that are not a closing parenthesis : `[^\)]+`

  - This being captured, so we can use it later : `([^\)]+)`
  - And this first *(and only, here)* captured thing will be available as `$matches[1]`
- A closing `)` ; here, too, it's a special character that has to be escaped : `\)`

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$text = "blah blah blah (here is the bit I'd like to extract)";
$matches = array();
if(preg_match('!\(([^)]+)!', $text, $matches))
{
    echo "Text in brackets is: " . $matches[1] . "\n";
}
```